# Generate a random key including current inserting column value in oracle is it possible to create

Tags: oracle10g

I'm trying to generate a random key including current inserting column value in oracle is it possible to create?

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE
(
  KEY VARCHAR2(12) not null,
  SITEID varchar2(25) not null,
  SITENAME varchar2(50),
  CONSTRAINT MY_pk PRIMARY KEY (KEY)
);

INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (KEY, SITEID, SITENAME)
VALUES(('ABCD001'||SITEID), 'HYD001', 'HYDERABADSITE');
```

Comment: Which bit is supposed to be random? What is the `SITEID` in the `VALUES` clause, is that also supposed to be `'HYD001'`?

Comment: You may use a trigger.

Comment: the SITEID is which i'm entering nothing but 'HYD001' VALUE!

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use a `BEFORE TRIGGER` to do this. like,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
TRIGGER my_table_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON my_table
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
     :NEW.KEY := 'ABCD001'||:NEW.siteid;
END;
```